# How to get Text BOLD in Alert or Confirm box?

Tags: javascript, alert

How to get BOLD Text and change color of text in Alert or Confirm box?

```
var conFrm =  confirm("Following List(s) already Sent...!\n<strong>List Name:  </strong>"+ss.replace(",","\n<b>Name: </b>")+"\n Do you want to send again...!");
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can't do it. But you can use custom Alert and Confirm boxes.

You can read about some User Interface libraries here:

http://speckyboy.com/2010/05/17/15-javascript-web-ui-libraries-frameworks-and-libraries/

Most common libraries are:

- http://jqueryui.com/
- http://mootools.net/
- http://www.prototype-ui.com/
- http://script.aculo.us/
- http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/

Comment: How to do custom alert with scriptaculous ?

Answer (score 16):

The `alert()` dialog is not rendered in HTML, and thus the HTML you have embedded is meaningless.

You'd need to use a *custom modal* to achieve that.

Answer (score 11):

**Add this function to your source:**

```
function toUnicodeVariant(str, variant, flags) {
    const offsets = {
        m: [0x1d670, 0x1d7f6],
        b: [0x1d400, 0x1d7ce],
        i: [0x1d434, 0x00030],
        bi: [0x1d468, 0x00030],
        c: [0x1d49c, 0x00030],
        bc: [0x1d4d0, 0x00030],
        g: [0x1d504, 0x00030],
        d: [0x1d538, 0x1d7d8],
        bg: [0x1d56c, 0x00030],
        s: [0x1d5a0, 0x1d7e2],
        bs: [0x1d5d4, 0x1d7ec],
        is: [0x1d608, 0x00030],
        bis: [0x1d63c, 0x00030],
        o: [0x24B6, 0x2460],
        p: [0x249C, 0x2474],
        w: [0xff21, 0xff10],
        u: [0x2090, 0xff10]
    }

    const variantOffsets = {
        'monospace': 'm',
        'bold': 'b',
        'italic': 'i',
        'bold italic': 'bi',
        'script': 'c',
        'bold script': 'bc',
        'gothic': 'g',
        'gothic bold': 'bg',
        'doublestruck': 'd',
        'sans': 's',
        'bold sans': 'bs',
        'italic sans': 'is',
        'bold italic sans': 'bis',
        'parenthesis': 'p',
        'circled': 'o',
        'fullwidth': 'w'
    }

    // special characters (absolute values)
    var special = {
        m: {
            ' ': 0x2000,
            '-': 0x2013
        },
        i: {
            'h': 0x210e
        },
        g: {
            'C': 0x212d,
            'H': 0x210c,
            'I': 0x2111,
            'R': 0x211c,
            'Z': 0x2128
        },
        o: {
            '0': 0x24EA,
            '1': 0x2460,
            '2': 0x2461,
            '3': 0x2462,
            '4': 0x2463,
            '5': 0x2464,
            '6': 0x2465,
            '7': 0x2466,
            '8': 0x2467,
            '9': 0x2468,
        },
        p: {},
        w: {}
    }
    //support for parenthesized latin letters small cases 
    for (var i = 97; i <= 122; i++) {
        special.p[String.fromCharCode(i)] = 0x249C + (i - 97)
    }
    //support for full width latin letters small cases 
    for (var i = 97; i <= 122; i++) {
        special.w[String.fromCharCode(i)] = 0xff41 + (i - 97)
    }

    const chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    const numbers = '0123456789';

    var getType = function (variant) {
        if (variantOffsets[variant]) return variantOffsets[variant]
        if (offsets[variant]) return variant;
        return 'm'; //monospace as default
    }
    var getFlag = function (flag, flags) {
        if (!flags) return false
        return flags.split(',').indexOf(flag) > -1
    }

    var type = getType(variant);
    var underline = getFlag('underline', flags);
    var strike = getFlag('strike', flags);
    var result = '';

    for (var k of str) {
        let index
        let c = k
        if (special[type] && special[type][c]) c = String.fromCodePoint(special[type][c])
        if (type && (index = chars.indexOf(c)) > -1) {
            result += String.fromCodePoint(index + offsets[type][0])
        } else if (type && (index = numbers.indexOf(c)) > -1) {
            result += String.fromCodePoint(index + offsets[type][1])
        } else {
            result += c
        }
        if (underline) result += '\u0332' // add combining underline
        if (strike) result += '\u0336' // add combining strike
    }
    return result
}
```

**Call it like:**

```
alert('your chance is: ' + toUnicodeVariant('100%', 'bold sans', 'bold'));
```

[image]

**Read more about this here:** https://github.com/davidkonrad/toUnicodeVariant

Comment: I have been building sites since 1994 and never knew this was possible until today! Ha.

Answer (score 10):

Maybe you coul'd use UTF8 bold chars.

For examples:
https://yaytext.com/bold-italic/

It works on Chromium 80.0, I don't know on other browsers...