# How to stylize text in an alert box?

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get Text BOLD in Alert or Confirm box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620516/how-to-get-text-bold-in-alert-or-confirm-box)

In the following example I need to add styles to the word alert, so it says:

> Hello! I am an **alert** box!

Here is my code:

```
<html><head>
   <script type="text/javascript"> 
      function show_alert() 
      {
         alert("Hello! I am an alert box!"); 
      } 
   </script></head><body>
   <input type="button" onclick="show_alert()" value="Show alert box" />
</body></html>
```

Comment: Try building your own alert box.

Comment: This question gave me the idea of building a plug in to make OS like alert boxes. Just like what Apple did in iCloud. Should I call it alert.js?

Answer (score 4):

Basically it's impossible. You don't have access to OS level from inside the browser.

All you can do is using a custom modal popup. You can find tons of ready to use modal popup plug ins [here](http://choosedaily.com/1178/15-jquery-popup-modal-dialog-plugins-tutorials/) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756342/whats-your-favorite-jquery-modal-plugin)

`window.alert` accept an `string` as it's argument. You can't style an `string`

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.alert):

> message is a `string` of text you want to display in the alert dialog,
>   or, alternatively, an object that is converted into a string and
>   displayed.

Answer (score 3):

The alert box is a browser window and part of the OS, not the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model), so unfortunately you can't apply styles to it.

The easiest solution is to use one of [many existing modal dialogs](http://www.javascriptplugins.com/javascript/plugin/modal-dialog-box/) along with the required Javascript library of the dialog you choose.

The alternative is to mimic an alert box by overlaying a specialized `<div class="yourAlertClass">` on your page, using Javascript or a custom library (like [moo tools](http://mootools.net/) or [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)) for the animations.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

I think what you are thinking of is a modal popup. Have a look in [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation), but there are plenty of other libraries you can use.

Answer (score 1):

[Alert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.alert), [confirm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.confirm) and [prompt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.prompt) **can not be styled**. They **vary** from browser to browser.

To make a *styled "alert box"* ( dialog ) you should use an **UI library** - [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) for [example](http://jqueryui.it/demos/dialog)