# Hoe and can you view and then edit the elements of a javascript alert box?

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, alert

you see there's a javascript function called alert(); which creates a popup/dialog box is it possible to inspect it because the alert popup's design varies and is different depending on the browser I want it to look like the alert popup of Google Chrome on each and every browser and to do that I want to be able to see the CSS properties and styling of the alert popup and then put it compulsory by using the !important CSS property for all browsers to use that specific alert popup design, but that's just what I think is the way to do it but if there is some other way to do it please let me know about it and how to do it since I don't know if it's even possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stylize text in an alert box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853321/how-to-stylize-text-in-an-alert-box)

Comment: You should use sweetalert , which is responsive and can modify

Comment: @MattEllen No it didn't I wanted to stylize the alert box but thanks to the accepted answer 54ka my doubts are now clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot manipulate the "Allert" box on the browser. But you can create your own using a modal dialog box.

This example is a very simple preview of a custom modal window that you can change as you wish

```js
function showModal() {
    var mod = document.getElementById('myModal');
    mod.innerHTML = 'Some text here!';
    mod.innerHTML += '<button onclick="hideModal()">Close</button>'
    mod.setAttribute('style', 'display: block;');
}

function hideModal() {
    var mod = document.getElementById('myModal');
    mod.setAttribute('style', 'display: none;');
}
```

```css
#myModal {
    position: absolute;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    left: calc(50% - 120px);
    top: calc(50% - 70px);
    padding: 20px;
}

#myModal button {
    display: block;
    margin: 20px auto;
}
```

```html
<button id="end-btn" type="button" name="" value="I am done!" onclick="showModal()">Click me</button>

<div id="myModal" style="display: none;">
</div>
```