# bold contents displayed in javascript alert box?

Tags: javascript, alert

I wanna make bold content to be displayed in javascript alert box. as far I know I gave `<b>` to make bold. but, it doesn't works. Is there anyway to make bold?

Code;

```
function f1()
{
alert("<b>Hello</b>")
}
```

Comment: Not possible with `alert`.

Comment: It's not possible but that link is helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620516/how-to-get-text-bold-in-alert-or-confirm-box

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Jquery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) for that.

Example:

```
 $(function () {
     $("#dialog-message").dialog({
         modal: true,
         buttons: {
             Ok: function () {
                 $(this).dialog("close");
             }
         }
     });
 });
```

Or a [jquery plugin](http://thrivingkings.com/read/Apprise-The-attractive-alert-alternative-for-jQuery)

Basically a pure alert box is a system object, and you can't apply CSS. However an alert box supports all Unicode characters and things like `\n` and `\t`

Answer (score 1):

Javascript's alert function does not support HTML tags. The alert function is strictly used for text output, not html or any other format.

Please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.alert for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Nope not possible to show HTML content in an alert box !

If you are really serious about this check out **JQuery's Popup** [Here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)