# Xpages adding some bold text in confirmation message

Tags: javascript, xpages

```
<xp:confirm>
    <xp:this.message><![CDATA[#{javascript:var txt = "bold?";

"simple text" + '\n' + '\n' + txt.bold() +" another simple text." }]]>
    </xp:this.message>
</xp:confirm>
```

But it seems the `bold()` function isn't working with this approach... Can I achieve this in other way(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xp:confirm` (as part of an `xp:actionGroup`) shows a simple browser alert which only supports plain text. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620516/how-to-get-text-bold-in-alert-or-confirm-box) for instance.

If you need more than plain text, you need to use dialog boxes (for instance `xp:dialog`).