# Enlarge pop-up and increase font size/bold for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, alert, onclientclick

I'm newbie, can you help me regarding:

1. Enlarge the pop-up to bigger size
2. Increase the font size or bold

---

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                        function script2() {
                            return alert('...');
                        }
                    </script>
```

The Code I use to call the function as below:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" CssClass="Button" OnClientClick="script2()" />
```

---

Picture as link below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jz139.png

Thank You.

Comment: anyone know about it? very appreciate if any of you can help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Text BOLD in Alert or Confirm box?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620516/how-to-get-text-bold-in-alert-or-confirm-box)