# Alerting bold Unicode letters turns them into nonsense

Tags: javascript, unicode, alert, mojibake

I am trying to alert bold text and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60432824/19275492) nulll suggested using bold unicode.

So I tried:
`alert('  ');` and it worked as expected. But when I tried to use the exact same thing in a different document, it alerts this:

ð—¡ð—¼ð˜ð—µð—¶ð—»ð—´ ð˜ð—¼ ð—±ð—¼ð˜„ð—»ð—¹ð—¼ð—®ð—±

What am doing wrong and why does it work in a different document with the exact same code?

Thank you in advance and sorry for my English

Comment: The best solution is most likely not to use `alert()` at all. It is very limited and not very user friendly.

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): `''.encode('utf-8').decode('cp1252','replace')` returns `'ð�—¡ð�—¼ð�˜�ð�—µð�—¶ð�—»ð�—´'` (and you don't see _unprintable_ controls `�` in your  output…) You see `''.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp1252', 'ignore')` resulting to `'ð—¡ð—¼ð˜ð—µð—¶ð—»ð—´'`.

Comment: Do not use "bold" unicode. You should do formatting outside unicode. It may seems a good idea, but it is not. You makes things less readable (such letters in any fonts are not designed for such task, and as you see, it is ugly). You make translation and voice interface impossible. Remember: formatting should be done outside Unicode so in a different layer (e.g. using HTML tags). "It seems to work" is not enough.

Comment: "*the exact same thing in a different document*" - sounds like you're sending the two documents with different http content encoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so i found the solution, and it's pretty simple. All you need to do is just put `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in the document head.

That works for me.